# Facebook iOS SDK session state closing randomly after uploaded to iTunes connect

Tags: ios, facebook, swift

I am only experiencing this issue after uploaded test builds to iTunes Connect, but not on any of my development builds.

Are there any "gotchas" that could be causing things to behave differently when the code itself is identical between the development and iTunes Connect builds?

What happens is the user presumably silently logs into Facebook fine, but then upon certain calls to our API, which only pass our API Token and do nothing with Facebook, the app then hits this line (couldn't use debugger, so had to use the alert to show the problem for iTunesConnect builds):

```
//let alert = UIAlertView(title: "Setup Guest Acct", message: "#3", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "Okay")
                //alert.show()
```

which means what the session state became closed. So I then sign them into one of our own guest accounts. Is this behavior normal, should I try reopening the Facebook session, or something else? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is the relevant Facebook code:

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication!) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    FBAppCall.handleDidBecomeActive()
    println("applicationDidBecomeActive")
}
```

...

```
func setupAppUserManagerBySigningInWithLoginFlow() {
    // Whenever a person opens the app, check for a cached session
    if FBSession.activeSession().state == FBSessionState.CreatedTokenLoaded {
        // If there IS one, just open the session silently, w/o showing the user the login UI
        println("Cached facebook token found")

        FBSession.openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions(facebookSessionPermissions, allowLoginUI: false,
            completionHandler: { session, state, error in
                // Handler for session state changes
                // This method will be called EACH time the session state changes,
                // also for intermediate states and NOT just when the session open
                self.sessionStateChanged(session, state: state, error: error)
            }
        )
    } else {
        // If no facebook token, check keychain info for user
        println("Cached facebook token unavailable, check keychain for user")

        var userID: Int? = SSKeychain.passwordForService(service, account: userIDKeychainKey) != nil ? SSKeychain.passwordForService(service, account: userIDKeychainKey).toInt() : nil
        var userAPIToken: String? = SSKeychain.passwordForService(service, account: userAccessTokenKeychainKey)
        var userGuestBool: String? = SSKeychain.passwordForService(service, account: userGuestBoolKeychainKey)

        if userID == nil || userAPIToken == nil || userGuestBool == nil {
            // If no user, then request a guest user to be created, set it up, save in keychain, save to UserManager
            println("user NOT found in keychain")
            //let alert = UIAlertView(title: "Setup Guest Acct", message: "#1", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "Okay")
            //alert.show()
            UserManager.sharedUser.setupGuestAccount()
        } else {
            // Got user from keychain
            println("user WAS found in keychain")
            if userGuestBool == userGuestBoolKeychainValueIsGuest {
                // Sign them into the guest account
                println("keychain user is guest")
                UserManager.sharedUser.signIntoGuestAccount(userID!, userAccessToken: userAPIToken!)
            } else if userGuestBool == userGuestBoolKeychainValueIsNotGuest {
                // Show them the Facebook login UI and give them chance to sign in
                println("keychain user is NOT guest")
                FBSession.openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions(facebookSessionPermissions, allowLoginUI: true,
                    completionHandler: { session, state, error in
                        // Handler for session state changes
                        // This method will be called EACH time the session state changes,
                        // also for intermediate states and NOT just when the session open
                        self.sessionStateChanged(session, state: state, error: error)
                    }
                )
            } else {
                println("ERROR: invalid guest bool keychain value")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

...

```
// MARK: Facebook SDK related code

func sessionStateChanged(session: FBSession, state: FBSessionState, error: NSError!) {
    // Handles ALL the session state changes in the app

    // Handle the session state
    // Usually the only interesting states are opened session, closed session, and failed login
    if error == nil && state == FBSessionState.Open { //FBSessionStateOpen {
        println("Facebook session state change: Open")

        let accessTokenData = session.accessTokenData
        let userFBAccessToken = accessTokenData.accessToken
        println("Facebook session access token:\(userFBAccessToken)")

        var userID: Int? = SSKeychain.passwordForService(service, account: userIDKeychainKey) != nil ? SSKeychain.passwordForService(service, account: userIDKeychainKey).toInt() : nil
        var userAPIToken: String? = SSKeychain.passwordForService(service, account: userAccessTokenKeychainKey)

        if userID != nil && userAPIToken != nil {
            println("Found userID and userAPIToken from keychain, sign in with Facebook account")

            println("userID from keychain:\(userID)")
            println("userAPIToken from keychain:\(userAPIToken)")
            println("userfbAuthToken:\(userFBAccessToken)")

            if userFBAccessToken != nil {
                UserManager.sharedUser.signIntoFullAccount(userID!, userAccessToken: userAPIToken!, fbAuthToken: userFBAccessToken)
            } else {
                // Reset all data and let user know to sign back into facebook
                // The Facebook SDK session state will change to closed / login failed, and will be handled accordingly
                /*
                UserManager.sharedUser.deleteAllSavedUserInformation(
                    completion: {
                        let alert = UIAlertView(title: "Facebook Information Expired", message: "The Facebook login information has expired. Please restart the app and sign in again. The temporary new guest account that has been provided does not have any information from the Facebook verified account", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "Ok")
                        alert.show()
                    }
                )*/

                // Try to have them sign back into Facebook
                FBSession.openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions(facebookSessionPermissions, allowLoginUI: true,
                    completionHandler: { session, state, error in
                        // Handler for session state changes
                        // This method will be called EACH time the session state changes,
                        // also for intermediate states and NOT just when the session open
                        self.sessionStateChanged(session, state: state, error: error)
                    }
                )
            }
        } else {
            println("UserID and userAPIToken NOT found from keychain, setup guest user")
            //let alert = UIAlertView(title: "Setup Guest Acct", message: "#2", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "Okay")
            //alert.show()
            UserManager.sharedUser.setupGuestAccount()
        }
    } else if (state == FBSessionState.Closed) || (state == FBSessionState.ClosedLoginFailed) {
        // was using FBSessionStateClosed and FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed until using forked facebook iOS SDK
        // If the session is closed, delete all old info and setup a guest account if the user had a full account
        println("Facebook session state change: Closed/Login Failed")

        if UserManager.sharedUser.guest != nil && UserManager.sharedUser.guest == false {
            println("User was NOT a guest; delete all their saved info & clear facebook token, setup new guest account")
            UserManager.sharedUser.deleteAllSavedUserInformation(
                completion: {
                    //let alert = UIAlertView(title: "Setup Guest Acct", message: "#3", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "Okay")
                    //alert.show()
                    UserManager.sharedUser.setupGuestAccount()
                }
            )
        } else {
            // If user was a guest (could only occur during sign in...?) then just delete the facebook info
            println("User WAS a guest; clear facebook token")
            FBSession.activeSession().closeAndClearTokenInformation()
            // Make sure splash screen would get closed at this point in the Login Flow
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(FinishedLoginFlowNotification, object: nil)
        }
    } else if (error != nil) {
        println("Facebook session state change: Error")
        // Make sure splash screen would get closed at this point in the Login Flow
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(FinishedLoginFlowNotification, object: nil)

        var alertText: String?
        var alertTitle: String?
        // If the error requires people using an app to make an action outside of the app in order to recover
        if FBErrorUtility.shouldNotifyUserForError(error) == true {
            alertTitle = "Session Error"
            alertText = FBErrorUtility.userMessageForError(error)
            let alert = UIAlertView(title: alertTitle, message: alertText, delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "Ok")
            alert.show()
        } else {
            // If the user cancelled login, do nothing
            if FBErrorUtility.errorCategoryForError(error) == FBErrorCategory.UserCancelled {
                println("User cancelled login")
            } else if FBErrorUtility.errorCategoryForError(error) == FBErrorCategory.AuthenticationReopenSession {
                // If session closure outside of the app happened
                alertTitle = "Session Error"
                alertText = "Your Facebook current session is no longer valid. Please log in again."
                let alert = UIAlertView(title: alertTitle, message: alertText, delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "Ok")
                alert.show()
            } else {
                // All other errors handled with generic message
                // Get more info from the error
                // TODO: figure out a way around this issue
                /*
                let errorMessageObject: AnyObject? = error.userInfo["com.facebook.sdk:ParsedJSONResponseKey"]?["body"]?["error"]?["message"]

                if let errorMessage = errorMessageObject as? String {
                    alertTitle = "Something went wrong"
                    alertText = "Please retry. If the problem persists contact us and mention this error code: \(errorMessage)"
                    let alert = UIAlertView(title: alertTitle, message: alertText, delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "Ok")
                    alert.show()

                }
                */
            }
        }
        // Clear the token for all errors
        FBSession.activeSession().closeAndClearTokenInformation()
        // Show the user the logged out UI
    }
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(FacebookSessionChangeNotification, object: nil)
}

// Manages results of all the actions taken outside the app (successful login/auth or cancellation)
func application(application: UIApplication!, openURL url: NSURL!, sourceApplication: String!, annotation: AnyObject!) -> Bool {
    return FBAppCall.handleOpenURL(url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication)
}
```

}